# How to check if a property is decorated with a custom attribute using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, attributes, roslyn

I want to analyse a C# class using Roslyn and intend to do something when visited property has the specific attribute applied to it. How can I do this in the `CSharpSyntaxWalker.VisitPropertyDeclaration` method override?

For example, in the following code block I want to know whether the `Date` property has the `Validation` attribute or not, and if so, whether `IsJDate` is true or false?

```
[Validation(IsJDate=true)]
public string Date {get; set;}
```

Initializations:

```
filesPath.ToList().ForEach(csFilePath =>
{
    SyntaxTree csSyntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(csFileSourceCode);
    // ....
}
_compiledCsCodes = CSharpCompilation.Create("CSClassesAssembly", csFiles.Select(cs => cs.CSSyntaxTree ), references);
foreach (CsFile csFile in csFiles)
{
     csFile.FileSemanticModel = _compiledCsCodes.GetSemanticModel(csFile.FullSyntaxTree);
}
```

Comment: where did your csFiles come form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution by making some changes to Yuriy's answer as following:

```
foreach (var attribute in node.AttributeLists.SelectMany(al => al.Attributes))
{
    if (csFile.FileSemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(attribute).Type.ToDisplayString() == "Proj.Attributes.ValidationAttribute")
    {
        var arg = attribute.ArgumentList.Arguments.FirstOrDefault(aa => aa.NameEquals.Name.Identifier.Text == "IsJDate");
        if (arg != null && arg.Expression.IsKind(SyntaxKind.TrueLiteralExpression))
            validationKind = ValidationKind.JDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the semantic model to get the bound `ISymbol` for the property, then call `GetAttributes()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tryed to get `ISymbol` by `csFile.FileSemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol` but Symbol was null.